# "Update" statement has "unrecognized name" problem on "Set"

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-update

When I try to update an existing table by inserting a new column, BigQuery states the error *"Unrecognized name: start_geo_concat"*. This is odd because I already created a column in another table using this same query formula. I tried changing the name or casting as a STRING but that did also not work. Any ideas?

```
UPDATE 
  `red-freedom-357915.CyclisticBikeShare.BikeGeoData`
SET
  start_geo_concat = CONCAT(slat_round, " , ", slng_round)
WHERE
  ride_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Does BikeGeoData have such a column called `start_geo_concat` in it ? It really doesn't matter if the column is in another table.

Comment: It doesn't have. I know that I have to create a column first but somehow I managed to create and edit a column at the same time in another command.

Answer (score 0):

You say "inserting a new column". Does that mean that you're trying to create a new column using an UPDATE statement? If so, you can't do that. The column first has to exist in order to UPDATE it.

Try doing this first:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `red-freedom-357915.CyclisticBikeShare.BikeGeoData`
ADD COLUMN start_geo_concat STRING;
```

Comment: Yes, it worked that way, I ended up using this approach. What is odd is that I used this query down below and it worked on another instance. This is the query:

`UPDATE
  `red-freedom-357915.CyclisticBikeShare.BikeData20212022`
SET
  weekday = FORMAT_DATETIME("%A", started_at)
WHERE
  ride_id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Then that table must have had a column called `weekday`. The statement would not have succeeded otherwise.